# Very Low Quality flag still appears in the review queue

Tags: bug

I noticed that the VLQ flag seems to have been taken away, which makes a lot of sense, since it never really fit anywhere.

Flagging an answer normally shows this:

[image]

Flagging from review still shows the old dialog:

[image]

(From Late Answers)

It still shows the VLQ option. If it's been removed, shouldn't the review queue reflect that change? Maybe it hasn't actually been taken out and my browser is glitched?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VLQ flagging option still exists, it's just not *always* available. Specifically:

- VLQ is not available on [questions that are being reviewed for closure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286972).
- VLQ is not available on [questions and answers older than 7 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635).
- VLQ is not available on [questions and answers with positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258896).

Comment: My example screenshot of the missing VLQ flag is from an answer that's 32 mins old: http://askubuntu.com/questions/866285/why-does-head-not-want-to-give-me-the-filename-on-top-of-the-find-list. Is there also a voting  threshold? I've never noticed this behavior before.

Comment: Yes, that too. Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. This explains it. Weird that I've not noticed it before though.

Comment: Pity. For a minute I thought it had actually gotten removed.

Comment: @Seth If only :/

Comment: @Seth - So you'd prefer we use custom mod flags instead?

Comment: @AndroidDev if all you're going to say is "very low quality", no.

Comment: @Seth Thought so. So then what *would* you prefer?

Comment: @AndroidDev if I wish a flagging option was gone I'm not sure why you think I want you to flag with a different flag.. what are you considering VLQ and necessary to flag?

Comment: @Seth - So what's the proper procedure for dealing with questions that are VLQ?

Comment: @AndroidDev well that depends how you define VLQ, honestly. I've found almost 0 legitimate uses for the flag.

Comment: @Seth - Okay, so what would do do for something like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/860472/tftp-time-out-issue-in-ubuntu and this http://askubuntu.com/questions/859417/what-is-process-avpppnvxrk-its-using-high-cpu

Comment: @AndroidDev Certainly not flag them VLQ. Check them now.